# libsentencepiece.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory when creating BERTopic model

Tags: conda, bert-language-model, sentencepiece

I am trying to train a `BERTopic` Model in python. However, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.auto because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
libsentencepiece.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall `transformers`, install `sentencepiece`, and set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to the path to `libsentencepiece.so.0`. None of these things have worked. Does anyone know why this is? If it matters, I am running this script on a remote server. I think perhaps it may have something to do with conflicts with the dependencies, but I am unsure.

###### Python Code

```
from bertopic import BERTopic
model = BERTopic()
```

###### Full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1086, in _get_module
    return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import (
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/mt5/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ..t5.tokenization_t5 import T5Tokenizer
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/t5/tokenization_t5.py", line 24, in <module>
    import sentencepiece as spm
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentencepiece/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _sentencepiece
ImportError: libsentencepiece.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/om2/user/kmcclenn/item_analysis/openmind_python_files/scripts/test_script.py", line 92, in <module>
    run()
  File "/om2/user/kmcclenn/item_analysis/openmind_python_files/scripts/test_script.py", line 73, in run
    from bertopic import BERTopic
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bertopic/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bertopic._bertopic import BERTopic
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bertopic/_bertopic.py", line 48, in <module>
    from bertopic.backend import BaseEmbedder
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bertopic/backend/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from bertopic.backend._multimodal import MultiModalBackend
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bertopic/backend/_multimodal.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .datasets import SentencesDataset, ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/datasets/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .ParallelSentencesDataset import ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/datasets/ParallelSentencesDataset.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .. import SentenceTransformer
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .models import Transformer, Pooling, Dense
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .Transformer import Transformer
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/models/Transformer.py", line 2, in <module>
    from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig, T5Config
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1039, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1076, in __getattr__
    module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
  File "/net/vast-storage/scratch/vast/gablab/kmcclenn/bin/mambaforge/envs/item-analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1088, in _get_module
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.auto because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
libsentencepiece.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

###### Dependencies

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                  2_kmp_llvm    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.8.4            py38h01eb140_1    conda-forge
aiosignal                 1.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-timeout             4.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
attrs                     23.1.0             pyh71513ae_1    conda-forge
aws-c-auth                0.7.0                hf8751d9_2    conda-forge
aws-c-cal                 0.6.0                h93469e0_0    conda-forge
aws-c-common              0.8.23               hd590300_0    conda-forge
aws-c-compression         0.2.17               h862ab75_1    conda-forge
aws-c-event-stream        0.3.1                h9599702_1    conda-forge
aws-c-http                0.7.11               hbe98c3e_0    conda-forge
aws-c-io                  0.13.28              h3870b5a_0    conda-forge
aws-c-mqtt                0.8.14               h2e270ba_2    conda-forge
aws-c-s3                  0.3.13               heb0bb06_2    conda-forge
aws-c-sdkutils            0.1.11               h862ab75_1    conda-forge
aws-checksums             0.1.16               h862ab75_1    conda-forge
aws-crt-cpp               0.20.3               he9c0e7f_4    conda-forge
aws-sdk-cpp               1.10.57             hbc2ea52_17    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
bertopic                  0.15.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.9                h166bdaf_9    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h166bdaf_9    conda-forge
brotli-python             1.0.9            py38hfa26641_9    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7f98852_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.19.1               hd590300_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.5.7             hbcca054_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.5.7           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.5           unix_pyh707e725_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
comm                      0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
contourpy                 1.1.0            py38h7f3f72f_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cython                    0.29.36          py38h17151c0_0    conda-forge
dataclasses               0.8                pyhc8e2a94_3    conda-forge
datasets                  2.13.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dcor                      0.6                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.6.7            py38h8dc9893_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dill                      0.3.6              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
docker-pycreds            0.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
et_xmlfile                1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
executing                 1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
filelock                  3.12.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.41.0           py38h01eb140_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               hca18f0e_1    conda-forge
frozenlist                1.4.0            py38h01eb140_0    conda-forge
fsspec                    2023.6.0           pyh1a96a4e_0    conda-forge
gensim                    3.8.3            py38h709712a_4    conda-forge
gflags                    2.2.2             he1b5a44_1004    conda-forge
gitdb                     4.0.10             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
gitpython                 3.1.32             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
glog                      0.6.0                h6f12383_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.2.1                h58526e2_0    conda-forge
gmpy2                     2.1.2            py38h793c122_1    conda-forge
hdbscan                   0.8.30           py38h31356c5_0    conda-forge
huggingface_hub           0.16.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
icu                       72.1                 hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
imbalanced-learn          0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        6.8.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib-resources       6.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        6.8.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       6.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.24.0             pyh71e2992_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.12.2             pyh41d4057_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
joblib                    1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jsonschema                4.18.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonschema-specifications 2023.6.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.3.0            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.4            py38h43d8883_1    conda-forge
krb5                      1.21.1               h659d440_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.15                 haa2dc70_1    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.40                 h41732ed_0    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libabseil                 20230125.3      cxx17_h59595ed_0    conda-forge
libarrow                  12.0.1           hd2d78f0_4_cpu    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           17_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h166bdaf_9    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h166bdaf_9    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h166bdaf_9    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           17_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libcrc32c                 1.1.2                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libcurl                   8.1.2                hca28451_1    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.18                 h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.12               hf998b51_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 13.1.0               he5830b7_0    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            13.1.0               h69a702a_0    conda-forge
libgfortran5              13.1.0               h15d22d2_0    conda-forge
libgoogle-cloud           2.12.0               hac9eb74_1    conda-forge
libgrpc                   1.54.2               hb20ce57_2    conda-forge
libhwloc                  2.9.1           nocuda_h7313eea_6    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libjpeg-turbo             2.1.5.1              h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           17_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libllvm10                 10.0.1               he513fc3_3    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.52.0               h61bc06f_0    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.0                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libnuma                   2.0.16               h0b41bf4_1    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.23          pthreads_h80387f5_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h753d276_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.21.12              h3eb15da_0    conda-forge
libsentencepiece          0.1.99               h180e1df_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h36c2ea0_1    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.42.0               h2797004_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.11.0               h0841786_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              13.1.0               hfd8a6a1_0    conda-forge
libthrift                 0.18.1               h8fd135c_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.1                h8b53f26_0    conda-forge
libutf8proc               2.8.0                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.1                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.15                 h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.11.4               h0d562d8_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               16.0.6               h4dfa4b3_0    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.34.0           py38h4f45e52_2    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.3            py38h01eb140_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.7.1            py38hd6c3c57_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2022.2.1         h84fe81f_16997    conda-forge
mpc                       1.3.1                hfe3b2da_0    conda-forge
mpfr                      4.2.0                hb012696_0    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
multidict                 6.0.4            py38h1de0b5d_0    conda-forge
multiprocess              0.70.14          py38h0a891b7_3    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.9.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  3.1                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nltk                      3.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numba                     0.51.2           py38h0573a6f_1  
numpy                     1.23.5           py38h7042d01_0    conda-forge
openai                    0.27.8             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.5.0                hfec8fc6_2    conda-forge
openpyxl                  3.1.2            py38h01eb140_0    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.1                hd590300_1    conda-forge
orc                       1.9.0                h2f23424_1    conda-forge
packaging                 23.1               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    2.0.3            py38h01efb38_1    conda-forge
pandas-stubs              2.0.1.230501       pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh1a96a4e_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    10.0.0           py38h885162f_0    conda-forge
pip                       23.1.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              3.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
plotly                    5.15.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pooch                     1.7.0              pyha770c72_3    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.39             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.39               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  4.21.12          py38h8dc9893_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.5            py38h1de0b5d_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyarrow                   12.0.1          py38h39356d1_4_cpu    conda-forge
pygments                  2.15.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pynndescent               0.5.10             pyh1a96a4e_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyha2e5f31_6    conda-forge
python                    3.8.17          he550d4f_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-fastjsonschema     2.17.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-tzdata             2023.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-xxhash             3.2.0            py38h1de0b5d_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      3_cp38    conda-forge
pytorch                   2.0.0           cpu_py38h019455c_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2023.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    5.4.1            py38h0a891b7_4    conda-forge
pyzmq                     25.1.0           py38h509eb50_0    conda-forge
re2                       2023.03.02           h8c504da_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h8228510_1    conda-forge
referencing               0.29.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
regex                     2023.6.3         py38h01eb140_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
responses                 0.18.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rpds-py                   0.8.10           py38h0cc4f7c_0    conda-forge
s2n                       1.3.46               h06160fa_0    conda-forge
sacremoses                0.0.53             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
safetensors               0.3.1            py38h0cc4f7c_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              1.3.0            py38hc099248_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.10.1           py38h59b608b_3    conda-forge
seaborn                   0.12.2               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
seaborn-base              0.12.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sentence-transformers     2.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sentencepiece             0.1.99               h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
sentencepiece-python      0.1.99           py38h19bc81d_0    conda-forge
sentencepiece-spm         0.1.99               h180e1df_0    conda-forge
sentry-sdk                1.28.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
setproctitle              1.3.2            py38h0a891b7_1    conda-forge
setuptools                68.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sleef                     3.5.1                h9b69904_2    conda-forge
smart_open                6.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
smmap                     3.0.5              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.10               h9fff704_0    conda-forge
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.14.0           py38h31356c5_1    conda-forge
sympy                     1.12            pypyh9d50eac_103    conda-forge
tabulate                  0.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.9.0             hf52228f_0    conda-forge
tenacity                  8.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             3.2.0              pyha21a80b_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h27826a3_0    conda-forge
tokenizers                0.13.3           py38haefcc50_0    conda-forge
top2vec                   1.0.26             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
torchvision               0.15.2          cpu_py38h08b8839_1    conda-forge
tornado                   6.3.2            py38h01eb140_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.65.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
transformers              4.30.2             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
types-pytz                2023.3.0.0         pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.7.1                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.7.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
ucx                       1.14.1               h0aa22dc_2    conda-forge
umap-learn                0.5.3            py38h578d9bd_1    conda-forge
unicodedata2              15.0.0           py38h0a891b7_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   2.0.3              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
wandb                     0.15.5             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.40.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wordcloud                 1.9.2            py38h01eb140_1    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.11               hd590300_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xxhash                    0.8.1                h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
yarl                      1.9.2            py38h01eb140_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.16.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.2                hfc55251_7    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend you to create an environment for example:

```
conda create -n test_env python=3.10
conda activate test_env
```

After that you can install the package using:

```
pip install bertopic
```

Now we can check the installed packages in the environment using `pip list`:

```
pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- --------
appnope                       0.1.3
asttokens                     2.2.1
backcall                      0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache 1.6.5
bertopic                      0.15.0
certifi                       2023.5.7
charset-normalizer            3.2.0
click                         8.1.6
comm                          0.1.3
Cython                        0.29.36
debugpy                       1.6.7
decorator                     5.1.1
executing                     1.2.0
filelock                      3.12.2
fsspec                        2023.6.0
hdbscan                       0.8.33
huggingface-hub               0.16.4
idna                          3.4
importlib-metadata            6.8.0
ipykernel                     6.24.0
ipython                       8.14.0
jedi                          0.18.2
Jinja2                        3.1.2
joblib                        1.3.1
jupyter_client                8.3.0
jupyter_core                  5.3.1
llvmlite                      0.40.1
MarkupSafe                    2.1.3
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
mpmath                        1.3.0
nest-asyncio                  1.5.6
networkx                      3.1
nltk                          3.8.1
numba                         0.57.1
numpy                         1.24.4
packaging                     23.1
pandas                        2.0.3
parso                         0.8.3
pexpect                       4.8.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        10.0.0
pip                           23.1.2
platformdirs                  3.9.1
plotly                        5.15.0
prompt-toolkit                3.0.39
psutil                        5.9.5
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
pure-eval                     0.2.2
Pygments                      2.15.1
pynndescent                   0.5.10
python-dateutil               2.8.2
pytz                          2023.3
PyYAML                        6.0.1
pyzmq                         25.1.0
regex                         2023.6.3
requests                      2.31.0
safetensors                   0.3.1
scikit-learn                  1.3.0
scipy                         1.11.1
sentence-transformers         2.2.2
sentencepiece                 0.1.99
setuptools                    67.8.0
six                           1.16.0
stack-data                    0.6.2
sympy                         1.12
tenacity                      8.2.2
threadpoolctl                 3.2.0
tokenizers                    0.13.3
torch                         2.0.1
torchvision                   0.15.2
tornado                       6.3.2
tqdm                          4.65.0
traitlets                     5.9.0
transformers                  4.31.0
typing_extensions             4.7.1
tzdata                        2023.3
umap-learn                    0.5.3
urllib3                       2.0.4
wcwidth                       0.2.6
wheel                         0.38.4
zipp                          3.16.2
```

Now we can run the model without any error:

```
from bertopic import BERTopic
model = BERTopic()
```